# Links to Visualforce Pages in Lightning UI

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-design-system, hyperlink

How can we give a link to a VF page so that it loads in same window? The usage required is to share the VF page URL in a salesforce record.

For Ex, there is a link to a VF page in Task Record. We are dynamically setting this URL in task record. Now, the old URL is opening in a new window.

I understand that we need to change the generated VF page URL but how should it look like so that it can open in the same window from a text area?

Thanks in Advance! Peace!

Comment: are you generating link with a href tag?

Comment: Right now, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a bummer.

Having an URL field and populating the whole URL did the trick. I was expecting the URL to be populated in a text area initially, but then we are now ok with moving on to a additional custom field in the package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To open a link in same window you can use target attribute of a tag in html.

```
Account a = [SELECT Id, URL_area__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Company ABC'];
a.URL_area__c = '<a href="/apex/YourVFPageName" target="_self">Your link description</a>';
update a;
```

You will see link opening on same window